# Stubbing void method of spybean failing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

I have a void method `bar` in a service `Foo` as shown:

```
@Component
@EnableAsync
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo {
    private final SomeOtherService someOtherService;
    private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;
    private final FooConfig fooConfig;

    @Async("myExecutor")
    public void bar(A a, B b, ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, String> c, int d, int e) {
        someOtherService.doSomething(a, b, c, d, e);
    }
}
```

I am using `Foo` in `MyService` class,

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyService {
    private final Foo foo;
        
    public void execute() {
    // call foo.bar();
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to write a unit test for a case when calling `foo.bar()` can throw a RuntimeException. Here is my test class:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpyBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringBootMain.class},
            initializers = {ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.config.location=classpath:application-test.yml"})
public class MyServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private SomeOtherService someOtherService;

    @SpyBean
    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyService myService = new MyService(foo);
        Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException("failed")).when(foo).bar(any(A.class), any(B.class), any(ConcurrentSkipListMap.class), anyInt(), anyInt());
        myService.execute();
        // some assertions
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error while running the test:

```
WARN org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager -- 
Caught exception while invoking 'afterTestMethod' callback on TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener] 
for test method [public void MyServiceTest.test() throws com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException] 
and test instance [MyServiceTest@60fc4450]
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: Unfinished stubbing detected

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
1 matchers expected, 5 recorded:

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(any(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(any(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

I have tried other configurations as well including:

```
Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException("failed")).when(foo).bar(any(A.class), any(B.class), Mockito.<ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, String>>any(), anyInt(), anyInt());
```

```
Mockito.doAnswer(inv -> {
    throw new RuntimeException("failed");
}).when(foo).bar(Mockito.any(A.class), 
                 Mockito.any(B.class), 
                 Mockito.any(ConcurrentSkipListMap.class), 
                 Mockito.anyInt(), 
                 Mockito.anyInt());
```

But nothing worked so far. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works, can you please include the imports as well in the questions or use full method names instead of using them in static fashion?

Comment: also, how come you are using both `RunWith` and `ExtendWith` annotations in the same class. `ExtendWith` replaced RunWith in Junit 5 https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-runwith

Comment: Yes, that was a copy paste mistake, I have edited the code above and included imports for the test class. And my methods are almost similar, I just can't give exact code due to multiple dependencies and it might become confusing.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that when I use mocked `Foo` instead of spybean, stubbing is working as expected. @Dhawal, I appreciate your efforts and will accept your answer, but its still unclear why stubbing was not working with `@spybean`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't figure out the mistake in your code since several classes are involved, I can provide you with a solution with imports that works.
It may help you.

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpyBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import so.A;
import so.B;
import so.Foo;
import so.MyService;
import so.SomeOtherService;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:application-test.yml" })
public class MyServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private SomeOtherService someOtherService;

    @SpyBean
    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;

    @Test
    public void test() {
    MyService myService = new MyService(foo);

    Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException("failed")).when(foo).bar(any(A.class), any(B.class),
        any(ConcurrentSkipListMap.class), anyInt(), anyInt());

    myService.execute();
    // some assertions
    }
}
```

Here are the dummy classes that I created that was not part of your question:

```
public class A {}
```

```
public class B {}
```

```
public class SomeOtherService {

    public void doSomething(A a, B b, ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, String> c, int d, int e) {
    }
}
```